# Is there already a module that provides an unicode ready printf method?

Tags: perl, unicode, module, printf

Is there already a module that provides an `Unicode` ready `printf` method, which takes the same arguments as the built-in `printf` but where the width to pad and justify works with `Unicode` data?

---

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings; 
use 5.014;
use utf8;
use charnames qw(:full);
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my %hash = (
    Peter => "the knight",
    Rose => "the dressmaker",
    Franc => "the barber",
    John => "the farmer",
    Lucia => "the baroness",
    Merlin => "the s​o​r​c​e​r​e​r",
    Ace => "the two\N{PRIVATE USE TWO} headed dog",
    Elsa => "the miller",
);

for my $key ( sort keys %hash ) {
    printf "%-15.15s %s\n", $hash{$key}, $key;
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what is wrong with the current `printf`?

Comment: choroba: `perl -M5.010 -Mutf8 -MEncode -E'for (10,30,50,70) { say encode_utf8 sprintf "%${_}s: %d¥", "sum", 1_000_000_000; say encode_utf8 sprintf "%${_}s: %d¥", "合計", 1_000_000_000; }'`

Comment: @daxim: ***Way*** wrong answer. You need `Unicode::GCString::columns()` for what he needs done. Plus don’t call `encode` yourself, duh; that’s almost always a mentality error.

Comment: @choroba What’s wrong with `printf` is that it works only on printable ASCII, not on Unicode.

Comment: What is that \x92 string about?  That's not Unicode.

Comment: I changed the code. I'm not sure what it is, but it spoils the nice output.

Comment: @sid_com You have an encoding error.  `byte2uni -e cp1252 0x92` says `cp1252 92 ⇒ U+2019  ＜ ’ ＞  \N{RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK}`. Obviously that’s not the correct code point, but it gives you an idea of wherein lies the problem. U+0092 is `PRIVATE USE TWO`, which is an invisible control code not accounted for by `printf`, although it would be accounted for by `Unicode::GCString::columns`.  But that isn’t the right fix; the right fix it to figure out why you have the wrong encoding.

Comment: The text is from a web-page, so I suppose I made an error when importing the text or there was an encoding error on the page - the encoding of the page is ISO-8859-1. They have removed the text, so I can't check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re worried about widths of Unicode — including East Asian stuff and combining characters and control cocdes and all the rest — and `printf`, then the right answer is that you need the `columns` method from the [Unicode::GCString](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode%3a%3aGCString) CPAN module.

```
 use Unicode::GCString;
 my $gcs = Unicode::GCString->new($str);
 my $cols = $gcs->columns;
 printf "%*s\n", $cols, $str;
```

Other examples include this to get the grapheme length of the string:

```
use Unicode::GCString;
$gcs = Unicode::GCString->new($str);
my $count = $gcs->length;
```

This to reverse the string by grapheme:

```
use Unicode::GCString;
$str = reverse Unicode::GCString->new($str);
```

And this to access substrings by grapheme:

```
use Unicode::GCString;
my $gcs = Unicode::GCString->new($str);
my $piece = $gcs->substr(5, 5);
```

I apologize that this is not in the Perl core.  Yet.

Comment: Maybe I'll wait, until there is something premade.

Answer (score -3):

Basic support for character width as specified by TR11 is provided through [Unicode::EastAsianWidth](http://p3rl.org/Unicode%3a%3aEastAsianWidth) and [Unicode::Property::XS](http://p3rl.org/Unicode%3a%3aProperty%3a%3aXS). It should be possible to write a workable printf-replacement on top of them, but I do not know what is needed for full compliance.